# Issue in ajax function with file data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file

i have a form with 4 fields, one is file upload
before adding file upload it was working fine
but when i added file field and ajax function changed, nothing is working
i print_r post in php page, its not getting printed
my code is as follows

```js
$(function() {
validateNotifica();
});

function validateNotifica() {
  desc = $("#notificaMsg").val();
  title = $("#notificaTitle").val();

  errorText = $("#error-text");
  if (desc === '' || title === '') {
    errorText.innerHTML = "* All fields are required.";
    errorText.addClass("red");
    errorText.show();
    return;
  }
  errorText.hide();
  errorText.removeClass("red");
  errorText.removeClass("green");

  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'calendar/admin/php/notifica_events.php',
    data: {
      action: 'post',
      title: title,
      message: desc
    },
    success: function() {
      sendPushNotification(desc, title, function() {
        errorText.html("Notifica inviata con successo.");
        errorText.addClass("green");
        errorText.show();

        $('.other-quotes').empty();
        loadNotifications();
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {
      errorText.innerHTML = "* " + data.responseText;
      errorText.addClass("red");
      errorText.show();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="notificaEvent" action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class='col-sm-3 control-label' for='notificaTitle'>Titolo</label>
    <div class='col-sm-7'>
      <input id='notificaTitle' class='form-control' maxlength="50" placeholder='' />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class='col-sm-3 control-label' for='Type'>Type</label>
    <div class='col-sm-7'>
      <input type="radio" id="notificaType" name="type" value="important" checked="checked">Important
      <input type="radio" id="notificaType" name="type" value="notimportant"> Not Important<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class='col-sm-3 control-label' id="notificaAttachment" for='Attachment'>Attachment</label>
    <div class='col-sm-7'>
      <input type="file" name="notificaFile" id="notificaFile">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class='col-sm-3 control-label' for='notificaMsg'>Messaggio</label>
    <div class='col-sm-7'>
      <textarea id='notificaMsg' class='form-control' maxlength="300" placeholder=''></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="error-text" class="error-text form-group no-margin-side" style="display: none;">
    <span>* Tutti i campi sono obbligatori</span>
  </div>
  <div class="footer text-center">
    <input type='button' id='notifica_submit' class='btn btn-success send' data-loading-text='Sending notification...' value="INVIA" />
  </div>
</form>
```

i want to pass notificaFile to php page, but not working when i changed code

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" missing, you need to pass full form data
https://www.codexworld.com/ajax-file-upload-with-form-data-jquery-php-mysql/

Comment: added that also, then also not geting printed any response

Comment: You need to send de whole form with data : new FormData($("#formid")) in the ajax instead the json method